# Document library directly on edit form

Tags: document-library, custom-list, versioning

I need to have versioning with draft version and approval.
Custom list has only major version and not minor.

So i could use document library but i don't have document to upload.
Are there a way with content type or other to add default document without uploading document.

I explain.
I'd like when user create document. He arrives directly on the edit form and a "fake" document is uploaded transparency.

Comment: By dev or OOTB?

Comment: OOTB would be better

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create the document Library, with all needed metadata (aka fields, aka columns), and customize the World template so it contains in the body QuickParts for all fields you want users to input. QuickParts are automatically synchronized with document properties, that are automatically promoted (synchronized) with SharePoint columns.
Instead of using the SharePoint Web form, users will thus create a new Word doc in the doc lib, and use it as the input form.

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot use this solution because i have to use some jquery in the edit form.